# unexpected EOF while parsing error on a line that does NOT exist

Tags: python-3.x

I am not sure why I keep on receiving this error. Any help please?

```
students = ['Jacob', 'Joseph', 'Tony']
for student in students:
    print(student)

students = ['Jacob', 'Joseph', 'Tony']
for student in students:
    print(magician.title() + ", you got an amazing score on you exam!"
```

Then it says "Syntax Error: unexpected EOF while parsing" on line 9, but there isn't even a line 9. I have no idea why this keeps on occurring.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're missing a closing parenthesis on the `print(magician....` line. Since parameters to function calls such as `print` can take up more than one line, the parser keeps scanning beyond the line where the error happens, looking for the closing parentheses. When it doesn't find it and instead encounters an EOF (end of file), it raises the error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did'nt close the parentheses:
try:

```
    print(magician.title() + ", you got an amazing score on you exam!")
```

Comment: Ok! Thank you for such an early answer. I wish best of luck towards you and your family!